Mongodb $match aggregation stage with $in returning "$in needs an array"
MongoDB 7.0.8 running localy on a docker container.
I have documents on an aggregation pipeline that contain a my_categories array, this represents the categories to which this document is related.
When generating a report, I receive another array from the interface, requested_categories, for which the report is to be generated.
I need to filter my documents so only documents in which any of the my_categories entries appear in the requested_categories array are included in the report. This seemed quite straightforward, however I've spent the whole morning on it and can't make it work.
The "$in" query operator seemed to be the perfect fit for it but I'm having difficulties, and I don't understand why. When using the "$in" operator in the "$match" stage I'm getting the "$in needs an array" error message, even if the field is clearly an array.
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
If I try the following very simple example on my aggregation pipeline:
  {
    $set:
      {
        my_categories: ["ED", "AAL"],
        requested_categories: ["ED", "OD", "FEL"]
      }
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        my_categories: {
          $in: "$requested_categories"
        }
      }
  }

I get the "$in needs an array" error message - however requested_categories is clearly an array.
If I change the query to:
  {
    $set:
      {
        my_categories: ["ED", "AAL"],
      }
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        my_categories: {
          $in: ["ED", "OD", "FEL"]
        }
      }
  }

It works as expected, and all the documents get to the output of the stage as all of them have "ED" in their "my_categories".
Ideas, reasons why it doesn't works?
Example of the issue

Not fully clear what you are looking for, have a look at Set Expression Operators. Function $setIntersection or $setIsSubset should help.

Hi, I added more details to clarify the problem. My document already has the "my_categories" field in the database, and I get the "requested_categories" from my interface so that I can select which documents will appear in the report.
I just need to select all the document in which any of the values from "my_categories" are contained in the "requested_categories" array.
The "$in" operator seemed to be the perfect fit, however I'm getting this strange message...
I'll try the $setIntersection and check if the intersection is not empty, thanks for the idea!

In aggregation pipeline, use $in in the format of { $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }. Ref: mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/i

Hi @ray, thanks for the comment. I'm using the proposed aggregation $in on other queries. The problem with it is that it looks if a single value resulting from  is contained by . In my case I need to look if any value inside a first array are contained by a second array. So not really a good fit :(.

Following the idea suggested by Wenfried above, I could do a workaround using the $setIntersection operation. So, if the intersection is empty it means that there are no entries from the my_categories in the requested_categories array.
So, instead of using the $in operator, I have replaced it by this logic, as in the example below:
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "frames.objects.gt": {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: null
        }
      },
      {
        $expr: {
          $ne: [
            {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$frames.objects.gt.my_categories",
                ["ED", "OD", "FEL"]
              ]
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


I would say $setIsSubset would be a better alternative in terms of readability, but this is just my opinion

Hi @ray, the problem with "setIsSubset" is that it will look for the complete first array in the second array, so:

$setIsSubset: [ [ A, B], [B, C, D] ] -> false

While I need to test if ANY element of the first array is in the second array (in this case I would have wanted true as an answer, as B is part of both arrays).
